# Fetching most recent items from Core data Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to fetch the 10 most recent items ONLY from a core data store. I have set the `fetchLimit` to 10, which returns the first 10 items  that were added to the store. How do I fetch the last 10 items?

Some possible solutions I have come across suggest sorting the request using `sortDescriptors` and `Date` attribute. But this results in undesired behaviour (items being sorted by date instead of chronological order), so I am looking for alternative solutions.

Setting `fetchOffset` to fetch result count - 10 could be a possible answer but I don't think it is impossible to get the result count before executing the request.

```
        let managedContext = PersistenceService.managedObjectContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Clip")
        
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 10
          do{
             let clipItem = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            
             mainClips = clipItem as! [Clip]
          } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            NSApplication.shared.presentError(nserror)
          }
```

Comment: Think you need to have some attribute on the items you're sorting which will give 'the right order'. This could be a rolling index number, or a `Date` (which is normally actually a Date + *Time*). Not sure I understand what the difference is between sorting by dates, and sorting in chronological order - aren't they the same thing?

Comment: You are right, sorting by dates and chronological order is the same. But I'm displaying the most recent item at the top of a list and if I want it to be resistant to any manual date changes. Your rolling number suggestion seem like a better solution in my case.

Comment: Either that or a separate 'dateAdded' attribute, which is just used for this purpose (and separate from the manually editable date) might help.

Comment: If you are using manual code generation ("codegen") for your entity you could make the date property private to avoid it being changed